# Operating Systems: Process State Transition Diagram

Tags: process, operating-system

what is the minimum processes that are in each state(READY,RUNNING,BLOCKED,SUSPEND) the same time?

Comment: OSdev seems like it'd be under the umbrella of programming development to me - and if not, well, move to programmers.stackexchange I guess.

Comment: This looks like the exact question my professor gave me last semester in my OS class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero. Whoever said an OS had to have processes (in the strict sense of the term) running all the time? For example, in the early stages of the Linux boot process, the idle process is not yet created, and so one could say that there are no processes in the system. That said, the answer might be different if you specified your question in more detail (what OS, what stage of the boot process, what do you consider a process). :)

Comment: There's a lot of variation in OSes even these days, and it depends on how you define your terms. Maype you should check what definitions your textbook uses?